# How can I add an item to a ListBox in C# and WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add items to a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) in WinForms.

I have tried:

```
list.DisplayMember = "clan";
list.ValueMember = sifOsoba;
```

How can I add `ValueMember` to the list with an `int` value and some text for the `DisplayMember`?

```
list.Items.add(?)
```

*Btw. I can't use `ListBoxItem` for any reasons.*

Comment: @jmein: Thanks; I missed the csharp tag in my effort to clean up the original post.

Comment: You might want to checkout this SO question: [C# - WinForms - What is the proper way to load up a ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303248/c-winforms-what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-up-a-listbox)

Comment: Please do not use the code provided in the accepted answer.  It is WRONG.  The class (ListBoxItem) suggested by monksy is a WPF class that lives in a WPF namespace (System.Windows.Controls) in a WPF assembly (PresentationFramework.dll).  Windows Forms developers SHOULD NOT reference assemblies and classes from WPF in their applications.  The code may compile and run, but it NOT CORRECT.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
list.Items.add(new ListBoxItem("name", "value"));
```

The internal (default) data structure of the ListBox is the [ListBoxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx).

Comment: listBoxItem? why I do not have that?

Comment: You can just add an object - it doesn't have to be a ListBoxItem.

Comment: That is why I said the default item was ListBoxItem, with another object you must specify the TextField and ValueField bindings. I didn't mention this, because it would be distracting towards the answer.

Comment: This is not the correct answer.  The question was tagged winforms, and ListBoxItem is a WPF class.

Comment: ListBoxItem is a Winforms class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx

Comment: @monksy:  look at the page you linked to...  it declares that the class lives in assembly PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll) which is a WPF assembly.  Never mind the fact that System.Windows.Controls is a WPF namespace.  Controls for winforms live in the System.Windows.Forms namespaces.

Comment: This answer is indeed wrong, there is no ListBoxItem class in the Windows forms libraries, only with WPF
The answer below is right

Comment: This did it for me. Upvoted cuase i got an idea from the answer. lstEmp.Items.Add(new ListItem("name","value"));

Answer (score 33):

ListBoxItem is a WPF class, NOT a WinForms class.

For WPF, use ListBoxItem.

For WinForms, the item is a Object type, so use one of these:
1. Provide your own ToString() method for the Object type.
2. Use databinding with DisplayMemeber and ValueMember ([see Kelsey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732054/how-might-i-add-an-item-to-a-listbox/1732148#1732148))

Comment: That is not correct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx

Comment: @monksy, how is it not correct? The link you provide says `Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)`, which means the class is defined in WPF. A normal WinForms application won't even reference to the WPF dll.

Comment: I agree with @AZ.  Actually reading the documentation makes it quite clear.

Answer (score 9):

In WinForms, `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` are used when data-binding the list. If you're not data-binding, then you can add any arbitrary object as a `ListItem`.

The catch to that is that, in order to display the item, `ToString()` will be called on it. Thus, it is highly recommended that you only add objects to the ListBox where calling `ToString()` will result in meaningful output.

Comment: +1 for ToString() needs to be called, helped me a bunch! (my own fault for not overriding toString in the first place, I try to do this for each class)

Answer (score 7):

DisplayMember and ValueMember are mostly only useful if you're databinding to objects that have those properties defined. You would then need to add an instance of that object.

e.g.:

```
public class MyObject
{
     public string clan { get; set; }
     public int sifOsoba { get; set; }
     public MyObject(string aClan, int aSif0soba)
     {
        this.clan = aClan;
        this.sif0soba = aSif0soba;
     }

     public override string ToString() { return this.clan; }
 }

 ....

 list.Items.Add(new MyObject("hello", 5));
```

If you're binding it manually then you can use the example provided by goggles

Answer (score 5):

The way I do this - using the format Event

```
  MyClass c = new MyClass();
  listBox1.Items.Add(c);

  private void listBox1_Format(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ListItem is MyClass)
        {
            e.Value = ((MyClass)e.ListItem).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Value = "Unknown item added";
        }
    }
```

e.Value being the Display Text

Then you can attempt to cast the SelectedItem to MyClass to get access to anything you had in there.
Also note, you can use anything (that inherits from object anyway(which is pretty much everything)) in the Items Collection.

Comment: I found this solution to be really useful since I usually have a key/value I need to display in combo/listbox controls. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to add a string to it, the simple answer is:

```
ListBox.Items.Add("some text");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an item of type ListBoxItem and add that to the Items collection:

```
list.Items.add( new ListBoxItem("clan", "sifOsoba"));
```

Comment: The Method ListBox.Items.Add() takes an Object http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.100).aspx
ListBoxItem seems only to exist as a wpf control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx
Since the question was about winforms (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.100).aspx) i assume that your method above is valid only for a wpf ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding integers, as you say in your question, this will add 50 (from 1 to 50):

```
for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x++)
{
   list.Items.Add(x);
}
```

You do not need to set DisplayMember and ValueMember unless you are adding objects that have specific properties that you want to display to the user.  In your example:

```
listbox1.Items.Add(new { clan = "Foo", sifOsoba = 1234 });
```

Comment: For some reason when I add a string to my listbox items collection, the listbox remains blank. Is there something else I need to do to make the text appear?