# Entering data in lists and displaying it

Tags: c#, list

Im doing a project where i have a series of text boxes, the contents of which need to be output to a class with properties which need to be recorded in a list of members of that class and displayed in a listbox. Problem is, I can't get those members of the class displayed in a listbox and think it may be because I am incorrectly adding them to the list, any help?

```
private void addmemberbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   foreach(Member m in memberlist)
   {
      puptextbox.Text = j.memberaddress;
      memberlist.Add(j);
      lstadd.Items.Add(j);
   }

}
```

Comment: What is "j" in your context? Where does it come from?

Comment: Who's the `j`? Shouldn't it be `m`?

Comment: You're also modifying the collection whilst you're iterating over it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How might I add an item to a ListBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732054/how-might-i-add-an-item-to-a-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** you need to use `m` instead of `j`. it won't even compile if you use `j` as `j` is unknown variable in `foreach` context

**2.** do not change your collection `memberlist` inside `foreach` loop.

```
private void addmemberbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   foreach(Member m in memberlist)
   {
      puptextbox.Text = m.memberaddress;
      /*memberlist.Add(j);*/
      lstadd.Items.Add(m);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition on what Sudhakar Tillapudi saied you should use

```
private void addmemberbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       foreach(Member m in memberlist)
       {
          puptextbox.Text = m.memberaddress;
          /*memberlist.Add(j);*/
          lstadd.Items.Add(m);
       }

    lstadd.DisplayMember = "LongName";
    lstadd.ValueMember = "ShortName";

}
```