# Adding Item to List Box

Tags: c#, visual-studio

<s>I'm having trouble adding items to a list box.</s>

For whatever reason, I can't get the item to display in the list box (nothing is displayed.)

```
 private void btnPressForCandy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtcandyMachine.Text = "";
        avalibleCandy = avalibleCandy - 1;

        candyDisplay.Items.Add("Candy");        //Key Line
}
```

Has anyone got any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance guys.

Joe

I've just realised that there's some other code effecting the list box.

```
        private List <Candy> CollectedCandy;
```

Which is why possibly it wasn't working.

```
        CollectedCandy = new List<Candy>();
```

However I'm not quite sure what I need to add to get this to work.
Obviously I need to call UpdateCandyDisplay but beyond that I'm not sure.

```
        private void UpdateCandyDisplay()
    {
        candyDisplay.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Candy candy in CollectedCandy)
        {
            candyDisplay.Items.Add("Candy");
        }
    }
```

Comment: wpf, winforms. what are you using?

Comment: Windows Forms I believe.

Comment: this works for me: `private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("test"+listBox1.Items.Count);
       
        }` I used the listbox items count just to make it easy to see how many items i put in there. also you might want to change the avaliblecandy to ` avalibleCandy -=  1;` or ` avalibleCandy--;` since they are a little faster from what i know

Comment: If candyDisplay is your listbox, then the code will work if the click event is hooked up to the button. Does the debugger hit it? is it shown in the button's property-event tab?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication11
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    List<string> _items = new List<string>(); // <-- Add this

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _items.Add("One"); // <-- Add these
        _items.Add("Two");
        _items.Add("Three");

        listBox1.DataSource = _items;
    }
    }
}
```

and more information use this link [How might I add an item to a ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732054/how-might-i-add-an-item-to-a-listbox)

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised that there's some other code effecting the list box.

```
        private List <Candy> CollectedCandy;
```

Which is why possibly it wasn't working.

```
        CollectedCandy = new List<Candy>();
```

However I'm not quite sure what I need to add to get this to work.
Obviously I need to call UpdateCandyDisplay but beyond that I'm not sure.

```
        private void UpdateCandyDisplay()
    {
        candyDisplay.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Candy candy in CollectedCandy)
        {
            candyDisplay.Items.Add("Candy");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fixed with  "CollectedCandy.Add(new Candy { });"

Thanks very much for all your help guys.