# Only display certain object properties inside a listbox databound to List C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox that is databound to a List with a bindingsource, what I would like to obtain is that the listbox only shows certain object properties like for example firstName,lastName instead of firstName,lastName,Address,Country,...

How could I manage this?

I'm using winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about create another type which will be your exact view model and use list of this type?

Comment: ViewModel ?? she is using WinForms

Comment: I mean to say "view model")

Comment: Like creating another list and copying the firstname and lastname values from the main list and setting the new list as the datasource from the Listbox?

Comment: @Andrew Ok, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

my last project was a big project in winforms,and i was told that the data bound controls effectively reduce the overall performance of the application.
so the whole group had to work programmatically when adding data to a control,let it be datagrid,combo box,or any other windows control.

i would suggest you do the same too,Adding data to your Controls using code.that way you also decide what you want your clients to see and whatnot.

i would also suggest you take a look here :
[how-might-i-add-an-item-to-a-listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732054/how-might-i-add-an-item-to-a-listbox)