# Name and Value (path) for ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

As a rookie in C# i'm looking for an easy  way to add 10 names with each a different value (in this case a path). I searched and searched and I think it cannot be done with C# Windows Forms but I have to change to WPF ?

It must be something like this

```
listBox1.Items.add(new ListBoxItem("Computer 1", "C:\001"));
listBox1.Items.add(new ListBoxItem("Computer 2", "C:\002"));
```

But the ListBoxItem is not supported for Windows Forms ?

Comment: See Kelly answers in that topic..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add an item to a ListBox in C# and WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732054/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-listbox-in-c-sharp-and-winforms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's supported in Windows Forms!

You have two options:

Using anonymous objects:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new { Name = "Computer 1", Path = "C:\\001" });
listBox1.Items.Add(new { Name = "Computer 2", Path = "C:\\002" });
```

Which would be displayed ugly.

Or by declaring your own class:

```
public class MyListObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public MyListObject(string name, string path)
    {
        Path = path;
        Name = name;
    }
    // to nicely display it in List Box
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " " + Path;
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new MyListObject("Computer 1", "C:\\001"));
listBox1.Items.Add(new MyListObject("Computer 2", "C:\\002"));
```

Continuing with second approach, taking into account answer by @MattWhitfield add this code to your app to see how it works:

```
// display Names of objects, this way you don't need to override ToString() method in your class
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

listBox1.Items.Add(new MyListObject("Computer 1", "C:\\001"));
listBox1.Items.Add(new MyListObject("Computer 2", "C:\\002"));

// select first item just for example
listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
MessageBox.Show((listBox1.SelectedItem as MyListObject).Path);
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot. But now I would like to add a button to open the folder.. he now takes both of the arrays. Is it possible he just gets the string Path ?

   int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
   Object selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem;
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(selectedItem.ToString());

Comment: @Mike See updated answer :) And accept, if it solved the problem. Optionally, you can upvote.

Comment: Solved! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add any C# object to the listbox Items collection, and then set the [ValueMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DisplayMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx) properties to tell the list box which members in your object represent the value and which to display.