# listbox troubles. I have no idea

Tags: vb.net, linq

Here is what I am having when I press the "Bills for Today's Orders" button:

[image]

I have no idea how to get rid of the "{name =".  I just want it to say "Michael Smith" and stuff like this.  I do not want the bracket nor the column header.  What am I doing wrong?  By the way, this data is from database tables.

Here is my code:

```
    Dim query1 = From cust In MICROLANDDataSet.Customers
                 Join ord In MICROLANDDataSet.Orders
                 On cust.custID Equals ord.custID
                 Select cust.name, cust.street, cust.city, cust.amtPurchases, ord.quantity

    lstOutput.Items.Clear()
    lstOutput.DataSource = query1.ToList
    lstOutput.SelectedItem = Nothing
```

Comment: Please fix your image link to a proper image type (`.png`, `.jpg`). A stream from flickr isn't helpful. If it's a supported type, someone here can include it in the post so that people don't have to leave the site to see it, and without it your question is a lot harder to understand.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a high enough score to post pictures or I would have.  Please forgive me.  Do you have any suggestions on how and where I can submit the picture so you guys can see it?

Comment: You can use a site like www.imgur.com to host single images externally.

Comment: You'll need a custom ToString() method override that you are happy with.  That won't happen until you declare your own type instead of using the anonymous mouse type that the compiler generates for you.  Use the *new* keyword in the Select clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the `DisplayMember` property

```
listBox1.DataSource = query1.ToList;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, .ToList will return a list of objects. So you will need to do what this post suggests and set the DisplayMember and ValueMember of the listbox, so it will display the correct fields instead of a list of objects.

[What is the proper way to load up a ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303248/c-sharp-winforms-what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-up-a-listbox)