# Converting multiplication to a String

Tags: c#, .net, string, type-conversion

## Converting problem

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am a beginner to C#. I am trying to make a simple times table helper and I get an error under the line of code indicated:

```
private void buttonShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxVal.Text);
        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i = i + 1)
        {
            listBoxTimes.Items.Add((i * val).ToString()); //'This is the line'//
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        textBoxVal.Text = "";
        listBoxTimes.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

**This is the error message:**

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add(object)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\sharptimestable\sharptimestable\Form1.cs   27  21  sharptimestable

and this one is over the `.ToString` conversion:

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object'  C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\sharptimestable\sharptimestable\Form1.cs   27  44  sharptimestable

Comment: Let me take a guess that you have just corrected the code at the end of the faulty line from ".ToString);" to ".ToString());" and that you haven't recompiled after making that correction.

Comment: The whole try-catch-finally code should be removed from this code. Normally this code won't cause any exceptions, just fix them if there are errors.

Comment: @MrFox `Convert.ToInt32` could _easily_ throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second error indicates that you forgot the parens on `ToString` which your *posted* code does not show.  Unless you fixed that when you posted the code that error is somewhere else.

Fixing that error should take care of the first error as well.

Comment: Ok thanks, I don't have any error's anymore, but it doesn't seem to add the items to the listbox.

Comment: @user3267723 The reason it is not adding the items visibly is because you have `listBoxTimes.Items.Clear();` in your `finally` block.  After you add all the items, the `finally` is clearing them.  Remove that and you should be good.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the add line to this:

```
 listBoxTimes.Items.Add(new ListboxItem("Name", (i * val).ToString()));
```

The internal (default) data structure of the ListBox is the ListBoxItem. That is if you are using WPF.

If you are using WinForms then you check out the following question:

[What is the proper way to load up a ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303248/what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-up-a-listbox)