# using a windows form, accessing a listBox and connecting it to multiple statements

Tags: c#

I am making a program that makes a user select the type of cookie they want with a constant price and the quantity they want; wither a 1/2 dozen , 1 dozen, 2 dozen, and 3 dozen. I am having a tough time applying my `listBox` which is named `Quantity` and its values to my if statements for each cookie pressed.  My whole if statement is red stating it cannot be applied to operands of type "double" and "void".

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const double CHOCOLATE_CHIP = 8.98;
    private const double OATMEAL = 6.98;
    private const double VANILLA_WAFER = 6.48;
    private double price;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });
    }


    private void close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        accumulated.Clear();
    }

    private void buy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void chocolateChip_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(chocolateChip.Checked == true)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)

                price = CHOCOLATE_CHIP * ((double)listBox1.SelectedItem * 0.50);

              accumulated.Text(price.ToString));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: under what conditions do you want the following code: `accumulated = CHOCOLATE_CHIP * Quantity.Add(0.5); ` to execute?

Comment: @marcusv What is the purpose of the `if (Quantity.Add(0.5) == true)`? What are you trying to accomplish with this logic? The method `.Add()` does not return anything (`void`) so you can't use that to check any logic.

Comment: This is just an assumption but are you trying to say something like `if (Quantity.Contains(0.5) == true)` which could be written `if (Quantity.Contains(0.5))` to see if the list contains that value?

Comment: If a person selects a 1/2 dozen I want it to multiply the quanity by the constant...I want an if statement for each quantity taken.

Comment: You need to show us then how the user would select the quantity value. You said in your question that is it a `Listbox` but when in reality your code uses a `List<double>` which are entirely two different objects.

Comment: Well when I type Listbox nothing pops up on visual studio only List does.

Comment: Then you need to show us **how** the user would make a selection. Where is the input? And you need to look on MSDN to understand what a ListBox is and how to use it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah I looked at that it doesn't make any sense to me..the user makes the selection by clicking what they want. there is a 1/2 dozen...1 dozen...2 dozen...3 dozen

Comment: What type of control are they clicking? That is the key!!! Show us a picture of your form.

Comment: I do not know how to do that...they are selecting from a listBox.

Comment: You're contradicting your code. If you say the user is selecting from a `ListBox` then you need to show us the `ListBox` code and the user selection code. If you *think* you are using a `ListBox` because you put in a `List<double>` then you need to **stop** and you really need to understand the difference between a `List<T>` and a `ListBox` before moving forward!

Comment: I know it is a listBox...I just want to know how to connect what the user selects to how the code is supposed to work. I've never worked with GUI's before I just don't know how to connect the data selected with the data on the form.

Comment: I edited my code I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to load up a ListBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303248/what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-up-a-listbox)

Comment: no not at all      .

Comment: I see you have an `accumulated` variable or control from the updated code I can't tell what that is. I don't know what `accumulated.Text(price.ToString());` is actually doing unless you tell us what `accumulated` is. Is it a List, String, TextBox, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I really don't think you understand the best use of a `ListBox`. Here is some code, using your techniques, that will get you what you want. I would highly recommend understanding all of the various controls you use or have access to so that your program is as robust as possible. Hopefully now you can use this to understand how to gain access to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` and use it in your calculations.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double total = 0.0;
    double COOKIE_PRICE = 2.24;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                // (* 12.0) Because the value selected is number of dozen.
                total = COOKIE_PRICE * ((double)listBox1.SelectedItem * 12.0);

                MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing was selected in the ListBox!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `!=` means "Not Equal To". So the line `listBox1.SelectedItem != null` means, do this block of code as long as the selected item in listBox1 **is not equal to** null. With a `ListBox`, if the user does not actually click on anything, the `SelectedItem` will return a `null` value. So, that check is to make sure something is selected from the `ListBox`.