# C# Listbox DisplayMember not updating

Tags: c#, listbox, sharpdx

I'm working with a list box but I am unable to get the DisplayMember to update properly and I'm not sure why.

What I have is list of connected joysticks that I'm attempting to display in a listbox.

```
        joyListBox.DataSource = getSticks();
        joyListBox.DisplayMember = "Properties.InstanceName";
```

The getSticks() method above returns a valid list of Joystick objects. I've verified that Properties.InstanceName is a string showing the friendly name of the Joystick. The program runs without error but only displays the default (toString) value of the Joystick.

Per request, I'm adding the getSticks() code:

private List getSticks()
        {

```
        List<Joystick> sticks = new List<Joystick>();
        foreach (DeviceInstance device in input.GetDevices(DeviceClass.GameControl, DeviceEnumerationFlags.AttachedOnly))
        {
            Joystick stick = new Joystick(input, device.InstanceGuid);
            sticks.Add(stick);
        }
        return sticks;
    }
```

Comment: Share `getSticks()` code.

Comment: If its possible, try to add a breakpoint inside your foreach loop to make sure each Joystick has a valid `Properties.InstanceName` field (e.g. not null).

Comment: From general links like http://stackoverflow.com/a/303283/6741868, it is suggested to bind datasource after displaymember, also specify a valuemember.

Answer (score 0):

DisplayMember should be the name of your property. Take an example. There is a class named JoyStick

```
public class JoyStick
{
    private int key;
    private string value;
    public JoyStick() { }
    public int Key
    {
        set { this.key = value; }
        get { return this.key; }
    }
    public string Value
    {
        set{this.value=value;}
        get { return this.value; }
    }
}
```

So, Display & Value Members would be like

```
        joyListBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
        joyListBox.ValueMember = "Key";
```

If this doesn't help you understand the usage of Display & Value member or there is anything else, then, let me know.
Regards!